# Controlling color=date in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am doing a simple enough line plot of before/after using the following code:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = preMax, aes(x=buffer, y=max, color=date, linetype= "dashed")) +
  geom_line(data = postMax, aes(x=buffer, y=max, color=date, linetype= "solid"))
```

This gets me the plot below:

[image: Example plot]

There are a few issues that I can't seem to work out.

1. The line type legend is reversed
2. The colour palette for the months is reversed (this is the priority)
3. Labelling each line to the right of the plot (I appreciate this could get messy - these are just diagnostic plots)

Although I've found plenty of solutions for 3) I can't work out the syntax for my implementation.

I have no idea what to do for 1) and 2).

Extracts of pre/post dataframes (please excuse scruffy headers read from CSV import - 'Masked' column is redundant here):

```
> dput(preMax[sample(1:nrow(preMax), 20),])
structure(list(type = c("Masked", "Masked", "Masked", "Masked", 
"Masked", "Masked", "Masked", "Masked", "Masked", "Masked", "Masked", 
"Masked", "Masked", "Masked", "Masked", "Masked", "Masked", "Masked", 
"Masked", "Masked"), buffer = c(200, 1700, 600, 400, 900, 300, 
1300, 600, 1500, 100, 400, 1700, 2000, 1800, 300, 1000, 100, 
1000, 1900, 1800), max = c(44.864783808451, 45.9712411935412, 
17.5829020162918, 12.4868639407346, 49.6003614709968, 45.2344134295274, 
21.1563882993978, 10.5763618088791, 37.6644106683852, 11.057020709424, 
33.3232497692325, 20.7153387275033, 37.6645113431222, 49.9596451668152, 
11.0570186079038, 45.6029948612003, 21.156362982432, 37.6638859359373, 
20.2727947583503, 21.5957031868673), date = c("2011-07-13", "2011-07-13", 
"2010-02-16", "2010-12-01", "2010-08-11", "2011-07-13", "2010-11-15", 
"2010-01-15", "2011-04-24", "2010-01-15", "2011-10-17", "2010-03-20", 
"2011-04-24", "2010-08-11", "2010-01-15", "2011-07-13", "2010-03-20", 
"2011-04-24", "2010-03-20", "2010-11-15")), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```
> dput(postMax[sample(1:nrow(postMax), 20),])
structure(list(type = c("Masked", "Masked", "Masked", "Masked", 
"Masked", "Masked", "Masked", "Masked", "Masked", "Masked", "Masked", 
"Masked", "Masked", "Masked", "Masked", "Masked", "Masked", "Masked", 
"Masked", "Masked"), buffer = c(1000, 500, 100, 200, 600, 1300, 
300, 1100, 400, 1400, 100, 1400, 1900, 1800, 900, 1800, 400, 
1700, 800, 1300), max = c(14.7852734070896, 14.9722784687354, 
15.2029852639159, 43.729031912867, 15.1848393092082, 51.7461939052593, 
24.5462660651035, 14.7020628187789, 51.660784286412, 51.6686452841226, 
37.4059816958464, 31.1296293850412, 16.3389454899921, 14.9904419060676, 
9.31826862882747, 37.5157587930802, 42.542644563124, 37.6102405759581, 
24.2312294619778, 42.7078563816514), date = c("2017-12-04", "2017-12-04", 
"2018-02-22", "2017-08-14", "2018-02-22", "2017-07-13", "2017-03-07", 
"2017-12-04", "2017-07-13", "2017-07-13", "2017-09-15", "2017-10-17", 
"2018-02-22", "2017-12-04", "2017-01-18", "2017-09-15", "2018-05-13", 
"2017-09-15", "2017-03-07", "2018-05-13")), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data? The easiest solution would be to combine `preMax` and `postMax` into one data set, with an additional column for pre and post values (let's call it "time"). In ggplot, you could then set `aes(lty = time)`.

Comment: jdobres' suggestion is probably best, but just FYI, the `linetype` arguments should not be within the `aes()` call if you want to directly specify the type.
`geom_line(data = preMax, aes(x=buffer, y=max, color=date),linetype= "dashed")` (and the same for 'solid') should have things looking as expected. But if a 'pre/post' legend is needed, which I guess it is, then jdobres' suggestion looks good.

Comment: Thanks, both.  I had tried joining the datasets but got a bit tangled.  Although in the example I'll add above thee months there is one dataset/month, in others there are two - one being used for the previous or next month due to Landsat scene availability. (On reflection,  I don't think that'll matter too much for what I need it for).

Answer (score 0):

**ggplot** is meant to use each aesthetic once. It'd be best to `bind_rows` on your pre and post data, and then plot the combined data:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- bind_rows(list(pre = preMax, post = postMax), .id = 'time') 

ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = df, aes(x=buffer, y=max, color=date, linetype= time)) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(ncol = 2))
```

[image]

As an alternative to putting date on the color aesthetic, you could use faceting for clarity (though this looks a little odd with the limited sample provided, it should give you the general idea):

```
ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = df, aes(x=buffer, y=max, linetype= time)) +
  facet_wrap(facets = ~date)
```

[image]